# Any benefit for targeting F# runtime for F# 4.0 or 3.1 instead of 3.0?

Tags: f#

In Visual Studio 2015 Preview you can select from three target F# runtimes:

[image]

Is there any benefit to targeting the newer versions? Do they give you access to additional APIs? If so, which ones? It would be great if we could generate a comprehensive list.

[F# Core Library Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353567.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to generate a complete list of new additions to the public surface area of FSharp.Core for 3.1 and 4.0. The code I used to generate the list of differences is included and can be re-purposed.

https://gist.github.com/ctaggart/0205da3f153cd20b099d

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a complete list of things that you get from referencing F# 4.0. However, looking at [the list of new things on CodePlex](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Status), there are a few obvious ones:

- Lots of new functions in `List`, `Seq` and `Array` modules (so that equivalent functionality is available in all of the modules where possible)
- A number of other library additions (search the table for "Library"), including things like `tryUnbox`, `isNull`,  `ofObj`, `toObj`, `ofNullable`, `toNullable` but also `AwaitTask` for non-generic tasks
- Out of the language features, the support for [quoting arguments of method calls](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/dsyme/cleanup/contribution/7638) is definitely one that requires the new F# core.

Also, I'm not quite sure which of these are actually in the preview - I suspect most of them are not.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. How about 3.1 vs 3.0?

Comment: @CameronTaggart : Notably, **massive** performance improvements to functions inside of the `Printf` module. You can find details about all changes between different versions on the [F# Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/) (you'll find a different post for each version if you scroll a bit).

Comment: @ildjarn I understand that there are performance improvements at runtime when using the newer versions. My question is really about *targeting* a particular version at design time. It would be awesome if a list could be gen'd with the differences in the metadata format that the Visual F# Power Tools uses.

Answer (score 2):

A quick-n-dirty way to see the deltas in the public surface area is to crib the code from the FSharp.Core [public surface area unit tests](http://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/fsharp/FSharp.Core.Unittests/SurfaceArea.4.0.fs) :-)

Create a console app with below code, and rebuild/rerun it against each version you are interested in.  It will dump all public APIs in that version.  You can use windiff or your diff tool of choice to compare APIs between versions.

```
open System.Reflection
let file = typeof<int list>.Assembly.Location 
let asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file)
let referenced = asm.GetReferencedAssemblies()

for ref in referenced do
    Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(ref.FullName) |> ignore

let types = asm.GetExportedTypes()

let values = 
    types 
    |> Array.collect (fun t -> t.GetMembers())
    |> Array.map (fun v -> sprintf "%s: %s" (v.ReflectedType.ToString()) (v.ToString()))
    |> Array.sort
    |> String.concat "\r\n"

// dump to a file or print to console
printfn "%s" values
```

Comment: I just made something similar, but not as quick and dirty. I created a gist that contains the public API documented as a .fsi interface file using the FCS & VFPT code. Code included. Use WinMerge or other diff tool to see the diff. https://gist.github.com/ctaggart/cd3f74cf366f2759311d